# How to fix hover conflict and enter event in ReactJS autocomplete?

Tags: css, reactjs, autocomplete

As a means to learn, I am trying to build an autocomplete feature. I am following this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/8lyp733pj0.

I see two issues with this solution:

1.) **Conflict with mouse hover and keydown.** If I use the keypad to navigate the list the active item gets highlighted and if I use my mouse at the same time another item will get highlighted. This results in 2 highlighted fields.

2.) If i select an item by pressing enter it will fill the input field with the selected text but if I press enter again it will change that text to the index 0 item I believe.

Can someone please help me in understanding how to resolve these issues. I have tried hover and focus for css but it still doesn't achieve the expected outcome.

My approach (not sure if this is the correct one):

- If keyboard is being used then the mouse event should be disabled and vice versa.
- I've also tried removing this.setState({activeSuggestion: 0}) for the enter event.

Thanks for your help - it's taking me some time to grasp the concepts of state with React.

Comment: I have tried removing the setState piece again and it seems to work now in the sense it doesn't change the input when pressing enter again

Answer (score 1):

- The `onKeyDown` function updates correctly the value of`activeSuggestion`. I sugest you to add a scroll in the select when activeSuggestion is not vissible.
- In my opinion, you need to update the value of `activeSuggestion` with the`onMouseEnter` function.
- When you do that, remember to remove the line 32 from styles.css: `.suggestions li:hover`.

**Only the element with `.suggestion-active` must have the active styles. Not the hovered ones. The idea is that `onMouseEnter` must update the value of `activeSuggestion`.**

- Here is the code:

```
// Autocomplete.jsx

//in line 84, after function onKeyDown, add:
  onMouseEnter = e => {
    try {
      e.persist();
      const currentIndex = parseInt(e.target.dataset.index, 10);
      this.setState({ activeSuggestion: currentIndex });
    } catch (reason) {
      console.error(reason);
    }
  }


// then, create const onMouseEnter after the render() method:
  render() {
    const {
      onChange,
      onClick,
      onKeyDown,
      onMouseEnter,
      state: {
        activeSuggestion,
        filteredSuggestions,
        showSuggestions,
        userInput
      }
    } = this;

// In the li nodes (line 123), add props onMouseEnter and data-index:
        <li
          className={className}
          key={suggestion}
          onClick={onClick}
          onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
          data-index={index}
        >
          {suggestion}
        </li>
```

- Remember to remove the line 32 from styles.css: `.suggestions li:hover`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Nico...that helped with the hover issue!

Comment: You're welcome @Heather!    Could you select my answer as correct and upvote it? (Arrow up)